# How do you check for a custom banner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a command block that checks if your holding a banner with an arrow on it, can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "With an arrow on it"? It's pretty tough to work out banners since they're quite so customisable.

Answer (score 1):

To check for an item in the players hand:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}}
```

Or if you want to check the players entire inventory:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}]}
```

To specifically target a type of banner you need to know the exact pattern of the banner, then you can use this structure to find it:

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {Inventory:[{
    id:"minecraft:banner",
    tag:{BlockEntityTag:
        {Base:15,
        Patterns:[
            {Pattern:mc,Color:4},
            {Pattern:flo,Color:15},
            {Pattern:tt,Color:4}
        ]}
    }}
]}
```

To break this command down, once you've selected the banner item, you need to know the banners base colour (in this example `15`) then you match each pattern on the banner inside the pattern array.

Each pattern looks like this `{Pattern:mc,Color:4}` including the the [pattern](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Banner/Patterns) and the colour. Stack these commands up so they exactly describe your banner, and it should correctly check if the player tested is carrying it.

**Command as you would use it (edited to match your banner of course) would look like this:**

```
/testfor @p[r=10] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:banner",tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:mc,Color:4},{Pattern:flo,Color:15},{Pattern:tt,Color:4}]}}}]}
```

Some good resources:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/recent-updates-and-snapshots/2179208-testfor-custom-banner-on-a-players-head

Comment: I suggest using the `SelectedItem` tag instead of `SelectedItemSlot` and `Inventory`.

Comment: Good call, I've amended the answer.